# PHP getting weekday hours

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I have a code where I can save business hours and weekday for specific business in MySQL. When the data is fetched from MySQL the output will be as follow:

```
Array ( [open_hours] => 0 10 0,1 10 0,2 10 0,3 10 0,4 10 0,5 10 0,6 10 0 )
```

`0 10 0` simply means `Mon 10am 12am`  and if it was like this `0 15 18` means `Mon 3pm 6pm`. This is not the issue as I already solved this by the following code :

```
$openHrs = explode(",", $openHrs['open_hours']);

        $weekdays = array('Sun','Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu','Fri','Sat');
        $res      = array();
        foreach($openHrs as &$temp) {

            $temp = explode(" ", $temp);

            $temp[1] = $temp[1] > 12 ? $temp[1] - 12 . 'pm' : $temp[1] . 'am';
            $temp[2] = $temp[2] > 12 ? $temp[2] - 12 . 'pm' : $temp[2] . 'am';
            $res[]   = $weekdays[$temp[0]] . ' ' . $temp[1] . ' - ' . $temp[2];
        }
```

Now how can I code more advanced so that if today was Monday I need only to display the output result of Monday ? Which is `0 10 0` or `Mon 10am 12am` ? Thanks for the help

Comment: where are u storing the numeric values of day in the above code??

Comment: @Sriniwas what do you mean?

Comment: nothin.. was just a misunderstanding.. :)

Answer (score 2):

U can solve this problem with this code

```
     for($i=0;$i<=6;$i++) 
     {
     if($res[$i]==date('w')) //get today's week number
           {
                echo $res[$i]." ".$temp[1]." ".$temp[2];              
            } 
     }
```

OR

```
     for($i=0;$i<=6;$i++) 
     {
     if($res[$i]==date('D')) // get today's weekday
           {
                echo $res[$i]." ".$temp[1]." ".$temp[2];              
            } 
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to filter out the `open_hours` with the weekday for today, the below code should do.

```
$openHrs = explode(",", $openHrs['open_hours']);

    $weekdays = array('Sun','Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu','Fri','Sat');
    $res      = array();

    $todayWeekDay = date('D'); // get today's weekday
    $todayWeekNum = array_search($todayWeekDay, $weekdays); // get number for today's weekday

    foreach($openHrs as &$temp) {

        $temp = explode(" ", $temp);

        $temp[1] = $temp[1] > 12 ? $temp[1] - 12 . 'pm' : $temp[1] . 'am';
        $temp[2] = $temp[2] > 12 ? $temp[2] - 12 . 'pm' : $temp[2] . 'am';
        // only add the item where the weekday is equal to today's
        if ($temp[0] == $todayWeekNum) {
             $res[]   = $weekdays[$temp[0]] . ' ' . $temp[1] . ' - ' . $temp[2];
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $i; // the weekday; comes as input

    $openHrs = explode(",", $openHrs['open_hours']);

    $weekdays = array('Sun','Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu','Fri','Sat');
    $res      = array();
    $temp = explode(" ", $openHrs[$i]);

    $temp[1] = $temp[1] > 12 ? $temp[1] - 12 . 'pm' : $temp[1] . 'am';
    $temp[2] = $temp[2] > 12 ? $temp[2] - 12 . 'pm' : $temp[2] . 'am';
    $res   = $weekdays[$temp[0]] . ' ' . $temp[1] . ' - ' . $temp[2];
```

Answer (score 0):

Well it sounds like a tough question but see if it is worth trying this:

```
$open_hours = array(Mon 10 0,Tue 10 0,Wed 10 0,Thu 10 0,Fri 10 0,Sat 10 0,Sun 10 0 );
$today = date('D');
$associate_array_key = array_keys($open_hours, $today);
$openHrs = explode(" ", $open_hours[$associate_array_key]);
foreach($openHrs as &$temp) {
  $temp[0]; 
  $temp[1] = $temp[1] > 12 ? $temp[1] - 12 . 'pm' : $temp[1] . 'am';
  $temp[2] = $temp[2] > 12 ? $temp[2] - 12 . 'pm' : $temp[2] . 'am';
}
```

This is only the concept that I could think of, surely there could be some manipulations needed for the code!